# Convert JSON IN LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-4

Here is my JSON

```
[
    {
        "TIMESTAMP": "2021-06-09 13:13:26",
        "COL1": "10",
        "COL2": "20",
        "COL3": "30"
    },
    {
        "TIMESTAMP": "2021-06-22 13:13:26",
        "COL1": "20",
        "COL2": "30",
        "COL3": "40"
    },
    {
        "TIMESTAMP": "2021-06-21 13:13:26",
        "COL1": "1",
        "COL2": "2",
        "COL3": "3"
    },
    {
        "TIMESTAMP": "2021-06-20 13:13:26",
        "COL1": "40",
        "COL2": "50",
        "COL3": "60"
    }
]
```

I need to refactor the json According to the Column name like **(EXPECTED OUTPUT)**

```
[
    {
      "TITLE":"COL1"
      "DATA":[10,20,1,40]
      
    },
    {
       "TITLE":"COL2"
      "DATA":[20,30,2,50]
      
    },
    {
      "TITLE":"COL3"
      "DATA":[30,40,3,60]
      
    },
]
```

I was tried but it not working

```
$data = json_decode($result, true); 
$refactored = array_map(function($item) {
    return (object)[
        'TIMESTAMP' => $item['TIMESTAMP'],
        'DATA' => [ $item['COL1'], $item['COL2'], $item['COL3'] ]
    ];
}, $data);
dump($refactored);
```

Someone help me out with this. The column may be 3 or more and it must be dynamic. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform your JSON like this:

```
$data = json_decode($result, true); 
$refactored = array_reduce($json, function($carry, $item) {
    foreach($item as $key => $value) {
        if (str_starts_with($key, 'COL')) {
            $index = substr($key, 3, 1) - 1;
            if (!isset($carry[$index])) {
                $carry[$index] = [
                    'Title' => $key
                ];
            }
            $carry[$index]['Data'][] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $carry;
}, []);
dump($refactored);
```

Comment: Bro, the column always do not start with COL.. In such case what we need to do.

Comment: You tell me. What should happen with keys other than COL*?

Comment: it can be any name

Comment: I understood. But the TIMESTAMP column from your example is missing. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I am always a fan of using the value you want to group your data by as a temporary array key, that makes things easier, and can simply be reset by using array_values afterwards.

```
$input = json_decode('…', true);

$output = [];

foreach($input as $item) {
  foreach($item as $key => $value) {
    if($key != 'TIMESTAMP') {
      $output[$key]['TITLE'] = $key;
      $output[$key]['DATA'][] = (int)$value;
    }
  }
}
$output = array_values($output);

echo json_encode($output);
```

Answer (score -1):

All you have to do is re-encode the processed data:

`json_encode($refactored)` will give you the output that you want.

P.S. you don't *have* to cast to an object. It works as array as well.